Error "Type mismatch: inferred type is ... but TypeVariable(T) was expected" implementing navigation type safety in Compose NavHost
According to this post, starting with version 2.8.0-alpha08 of Navigation, objects can be used in navigation.
I'm trying to implement it, because I need to pass instances of an object called ItemUI instead of passing a simple value, but it doesn't work for me.
This is what I've been trying:
ForYouNavigation
fun NavController.navigateToForYou(navOptions: NavOptions) = navigate(FOR_YOU_ROUTE, navOptions)

@ExperimentalMaterial3AdaptiveApi
fun NavGraphBuilder.forYouScreen(onTopicClick: (ItemUI) -> Unit) {
    composable(
        route = FOR_YOU_ROUTE,
    ) {
        ForYouRoute(onTopicClick = onTopicClick)
    }
}

NiaNavHost
@Composable
fun NiaNavHost(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    onShowSnackbar: suspend (String, String?) -> Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    startDestination: String = FOR_YOU_ROUTE,
    onReaderClick: () -> Unit

) {
    val navController = appState.navController
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        forYouScreen(onTopicClick = navController::navigateToTodays)
        // ...
}

navigateToTodays
fun NavController.navigateToTodays(topicId: ItemUI? = null, navOptions: NavOptions? = null) {
    navigate(topicId, navOptions)
}

At this line
navigate(topicId, navOptions)
I have this error:
Type mismatch: inferred type is ItemUI? but TypeVariable(T) was expected
I am following the navigation style shown in the Now In Android app.

navigate does not accept nullable objects - what it is complaining about is that your navigateToTodays method is passing navigate a ItemUI? - a nullable object and not an ItemUI.
Since your onTopicClick correctly uses a non-null ItemUI type, you should change your method to also take a non-null ItemUI:
fun NavController.navigateToTodays(topicId: ItemUI, navOptions: NavOptions? = null) {
    navigate(topicId, navOptions)
}

